# select only the column names from a csv in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am attempting to read only the Header (column names) from a csv file in postgres. Is there any way to do that? Or am i required to dump the csv data into a temp table and read the column names from there?

CSV:

```
id, column1, column2, column3
1, first, second, third
```

Answer (score 0):

With PostgreSQL v12, you could maybe use the new `WHERE` clause of `COPY` for that:

```
COPY ... FROM ...
WHERE NOT col1 ~ '^[0-9]$';
```

That will only load the row where the first column is no positive integer.

I won't say this is a fast solution, but it is simple.